# Python numpy: does indexing take precedence?

Tags: numpy

If I have two arrays, and I do stuff like `a*b[...]`, does the indexing take precedence over the multiplication? I.e. does `b` get indexed first, and then multiplied with `a`? Or does it index the product `ab`?

Same question by other operators (division, etc).

Or do I have to say `a * (b[...])`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Yes `b[...]` is done first.  You'll see that in many `numpy` (and python for lists and dicts) answers.